# How to specify CPU load in C?

Tags: c

I'm just wondering if there's a function that limits how much CPU this program can occupy. While my program is doing a hard job, I don't want my C program to take too much CPU and lag out the System.

Comment: Um... C is not C++.

Comment: See [setrlimit](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) if running on a posix system.

Answer (score 0):

In a program etched into a microprocessor, being *the only program that processor ever executes*, what would be the purpose of such a function?

No. In standard C there's no such function.

You might find one in POSIX C, however this implies that the OS is Unix-like. My suggestion would be [nice](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nice.html).

You're probably better off using a profiler to tune your program, so that the *hard job* runs optimally and uses less CPU... or buying a newer, faster computer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your system should be able to handle your program as long as it does not have elevated rights with regard to CPU time.  If you are using Windows there is a `Sleep()` function that you can execute every once in a while and this will halt your program's thread for a specified number of milliseconds but, again, modern operating systems do not allow programs to hog the system resources (normal programs anyway).  This includes Windows and UNIX (Linux, Mac) systems.

You can not do what you want to do in C.  You will have to tap into the operating system and then the code is not portable. It sounds like you want to keep it portable so I do not think you have any options.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that your C program will slow down the rest of the system unless you have take extra measures to make that happen.  That said, most operating systems allow a process to lower its priority so that it runs only if nothing else is happening.

In Windows you can try this:

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN);
```

In Unix it looks like this:

```
int myPriority = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, myPriority + 20);
```

You'll want to work out some specifics for yourself.  Higher numbers are lower priority in Unix, but +20 is somewhat arbitrary.